# What is this notation called and how does it work?

Tags: notation, finance

I came across this formula in a Theory of Interest class. I've never seen this notation before and can't seem to find out how it is meant to be interpreted. What I do know is that it is used for ordinary annuities.

[image]

If someone could tell me what its called and how to interpret it that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If it's in a class, can't you ask the instructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation
$$
s_{\overline n | i}
$$
is shorthand for the expression
$$
\frac{(1+i)^n-1}i$$
which is the amount of an annuity of $1$ per payment interval for $n$ intervals. It is usually read as "$s$-angle-$n$ at $i$".

For example of usage, see page 245 of [this excerpt](https://catalogue.pearsoned.ca/assets/hip/us/hip_us_pearsonhighered/samplechapter/0321946111.pdf).